# Closing window without having parent (web)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

We have web application where a third party is redirecting to our page . On this page we have Close button given for which `self.close()` is used. As I understand self close will work only if we have used `window.open()`. The third party might not call using `window.open()`. We would like to close the window one click of close option also this would be on mobile browsers. Is there is a different work around for this ?

Comment: I don't think that's going to be possible. If it were, I'm sure someone would find a way to exploit it maliciously in an ad.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.open('location', '_self', '');
window.close();
```

or

```
open(location, '_self').close();
```

You Can try This !!